# Can't seem to access associative array with named reference in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, associative-array

```
# SETUP PHP81 SYMLINKS
declare -A cgi=([path]="/opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/php-cgi" [filename]="php-cgi81")
declare -A config=([path]="/opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/php-config" [filename]="php-config81")
declare -A phpize=([path]="/opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/phpize" [filename]="phpize81")
declare -A pecl=([path]="/opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/pecl" [filename]="pecl81")
declare -A pear=([path]="/opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/pear" [filename]="pear81")

declare -a symlinks=("cgi" "config" "phpize" "pecl" "pear")

echo -en "[INFO]: Setting up PHP 8.1 symlinks\n"
cd /usr/bin

for symlink in "${symlinks[@]}";
do
    echo -en "[INFO]: Creating symlink for ${symlink}\n"

    # Get the array that matches the string in symlink
    props="$symlink[@]"
    # Print out the filename property eg cgi[filename], config[filename], phpize[filename]
    echo ${!props[filename]}




    echo -en "\n"

done
```

There is the section of code giving me issues. It currently outputs

```
./upgrade.sh 
[INFO]: Installing php81 packages
[INFO]: Setting up PHP 8.1 symlinks
[INFO]: Creating symlink for cgi
php-cgi81 /opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/php-cgi

[INFO]: Creating symlink for config
php-config81 /opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/php-config

[INFO]: Creating symlink for phpize
phpize81 /opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/phpize

[INFO]: Creating symlink for pecl
pecl81 /opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/pecl

[INFO]: Creating symlink for pear
pear81 /opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/pear

The expected output is 
./upgrade.sh 
[INFO]: Installing php81 packages
[INFO]: Setting up PHP 8.1 symlinks
[INFO]: Creating symlink for cgi
php-cgi8=

[INFO]: Creating symlink for config
php-config81

[INFO]: Creating symlink for phpize
phpize81

[INFO]: Creating symlink for pecl
pecl81

[INFO]: Creating symlink for pear
pear81
```

This is now solved I posted the solution below but someone down voted it because they dislike my solution but the solution I posted is working. But you decide what you want to use. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're trying to save something like `config[@]` in `props`, and then use the indirect expansion to index into `config` through `props`? IIRC that doesn't work, `${!p[idx]}` indexes into `p` first (treating `idx` as an arithmetic expression, so if it ends up resolving to strings that _don't_ name an existing variable, it evaluates as zero, giving you `p[0]` , or just `p`, given how scalars and the zeroth element of arrays are the same thing)

Comment: I think it works better through a nameref, e.g. `declare -n foo=config; echo "${foo[filename]}"`. I also think there's an answer about this on the site, but I didn't test now and don't have the time to search...

Comment: declare -n foo=config; echo "${foo[filename]}" How would I use the corresponding array from the main loop in this example? Also when trying to use declare -n I get ./upgrade.sh: line 33: declare: -n: invalid option

Comment: What bash version are you using?

Comment: You must be somewhere in 4.0 to 4.2, where `declare -A` is OK but `declare -n` is not. Can you upgrade bash?

Comment: Instead of having 5 associative arrays (`cgi`, `config`, `phpize`, `pecl`, `pear`), each with `path` and `filename` keys, you would be better off having just **two** associative arrays (AKA "hashes") named `paths` and `filenames`, each with keys cgi, config, phpize, pecl, and pear.   Variable indirection is almost always a bad idea (and avoiding it is one the reasons hashes are useful). then you could just iterate over the `symlinks` array, which contains the keys for both hashes.

Comment: Why not a simpler solution:    module load php81

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found a the answer

```
# SETUP PHP81 SYMLINKS
declare -A cgi=([path]="/opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/php-cgi" [name]="php-cgi81")
declare -A config=([path]="/opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/php-config" [name]="php-config81")
declare -A phpize=([path]="/opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/phpize" [name]="phpize81")
declare -A pecl=([path]="/opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/pecl" [name]="pecl81")
declare -A pear=([path]="/opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/pear" [name]="pear81")

declare -a files=("cgi" "config" "phpize" "pecl" "pear")

cd /usr/bin

# Adding links to new binaries
echo "[INFO]: Setting up PHP 8.1 symlinks"
for file in ${files[*]};
do
  echo "[INFO]: Creating symlink for ${file}"
  link_name="$file[name]"
  link_path="$file[path]"
  if [ ! -f "${!link_name}" ];
  then
    ln -s ${!link_path} ${!link_name}
  else
    echo "[INFO]: Symlink to ${!link_name} already exists skipping this step!"
  fi
done
```

Comment: isn't that what @glennjackman already posted half an hour before?

Comment: (what I don't understand is why you'd switch to using `${array[*]}` instead of `"${array[@]}"` when the latter is more correct and you already had that in the original post)

Comment: @ilkkachu Nope its not, doing it his way does not work in this environment the way I posted does. The * got switched when I was trying to find the issue.

Comment: glenn has `for symlink in "${symlinks[@]}"; ... f_var="${symlink}[filename]"` there, while you have `for file in ${files[*]}; ... link_name="$file[name]"` there. Both put the array name and the index in the variable used for indirect access. And then  both use that variable in the same way: `${!f_var}` and `${!link_name}`. Barring the renaming, that looks exactly the same to me.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create an indirect variable for each index in the associative array:

```bash
for symlink in "${symlinks[@]}";
do
    echo -en "[INFO]: Creating symlink for ${symlink}\n"

    f_var="${symlink}[filename]"
    p_var="${symlink}[path]"

    echo "filename=${!f_var}  path=${!p_var}"
done
```

If you want to get more convoluted, make `cgi`, etc to be *indexed* arrays, and an associative array can hold the *index* of the particular property:

```bash
i=0; declare -A idx=([path]=$((i++)) [filename]=$((i++)))
unset cgi; declare -a cgi=( "/opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/php-cgi" "php-cgi81")
symlink=cgi
props="${symlink}[@]"
values=("${!props}")
echo ${values[${idx[path]}]}     # => /opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/php-cgi
echo ${values[${idx[filename]}]} # => php-cgi81
```

Clearly `declare -n symlink=cgi` is much tidier, if you can upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having 5 associative arrays (`cgi`, `config`, `phpize`, `pecl`, and `pear`), each with `path` and `filename` keys, you would be better off having just **two** associative arrays named `paths` and `filenames`, each with keys for cgi, config, phpize, pecl, and pear.

Then you could just iterate over the `symlinks` array, which contains the keys for **both** hashes.

For example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

declare -A paths=(
  [cgi]=/opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/php-cgi
  [config]=/opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/php-config
  [phpize]=/opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/phpize
  [pecl]=/opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/pecl
  [pear]=/opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/pear
)

declare -A filenames=(
  [cgi]=php-cgi81
  [config]=php-config81
  [phpize]=phpize81
  [pecl]=pecl81
  [pear]=pear81
)

declare -a symlinks=(cgi config phpize pecl pear)

fmt='%-6s\t%-39s\t%s\n'
printf "$fmt" "KEY" "PATH" "FILENAME"
for s in "${symlinks[@]}"; do
  printf "$fmt" "$s" "${paths[$s]}" "${filenames[$s]}"
done
```

Sample output:

```
KEY     PATH                                    FILENAME  
cgi     /opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/php-cgi    php-cgi81 
config  /opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/php-config php-config81
phpize  /opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/phpize     phpize81  
pecl    /opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/pecl       pecl81    
pear    /opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/pear       pear81
```

Answer (score 1):

If switching to ksh93 is an option:

```
#! /bin/ksh93 -
conf=(
  [cgi]=(
    path=/opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/php-cgi
    filename=php-cgi81
  )
  [config]=(
    path=/opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/php-config 
    filename=php-config81
  )
  [phpize]=(
    path=/opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/phpize
    filename=phpize81
  )
  [pecl]=(
    path=/opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/pecl
    filename=pecl81
  )
  [pear]=(
    path=/opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/pear
    filename=pear81
  )
)

print "[INFO]: Setting up PHP 8.1 symlinks"
cd /usr/bin || exit

for symlink in "${!conf[@]}"; do
    print -r "[INFO]: Creating symlink for ${symlink}"

    print -r ln -s -- "${conf[$symlink].path}" "${conf[$symlink].filename}"
done
```

Would give something like:

```
[INFO]: Setting up PHP 8.1 symlinks
[INFO]: Creating symlink for cgi
ln -s -- /opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/php-cgi php-cgi81
[INFO]: Creating symlink for config
ln -s -- /opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/php-config php-config81
[INFO]: Creating symlink for pear
ln -s -- /opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/pear pear81
[INFO]: Creating symlink for pecl
ln -s -- /opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/pecl pecl81
[INFO]: Creating symlink for phpize
ln -s -- /opt/remi/php81/root/usr/bin/phpize phpize81
```

Though here, It seems you should be able to do just:

```
#! /bin/sh -
version=81
srcdir=/opt/remi/php$version/root/usr/bin
dstdir=/usr/bin
info() { printf '[INFO] %s\n' "$1"; }

info "Setting up PHP $version symlinks"
for file in php-cgi php-config pear pecl phpize; do
  info "Creating symlink for $file"
  ln -s -- "$srcdir/$file" "$dstdir/$file$version" || exit
done
```

Without having to repeat yourself that much and remove the dependency to bash or ksh93.